# Check if interface is extending another interface in Java using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, extend

How to check reflectively in Java if interface extends another interface? I tried this:

```
  for (Class<?> aClass : classes) {
            int modifier = aClass.getModifiers();
            if (Modifier.isInterface(modifier)) {
                if (aClass.getSuperclass() != null && aClass.getSuperclass().equals(TopWorker.class)) {
                    log.info(aClass.getSimpleName() + " extends abstract  " + TopWorker.class.getSimpleName());
                }
            }
        }
```

Check for Superclass is not working (interface is not a class)
Thanks

Comment: maybe using `TopWorker.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass)`

Comment: or maybe is the other way around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface can extend multiple interfaces (just like classes can implement multiple interfaces). As such, checking which interfaces are extended is simply a matter of calling `aClass.getInterfaces()`.

For your use case it is probably simpler to just call `isAssignableFrom`:

```java
if (TopWorker.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass)) {

}
```